# Reading or Converting the 17 digits timestamp into date time format C#

Tags: c#, timestamp, datetime-format

I am creating the Microsoft teams recording bot. I am receiving the timestamp along with the video media streams that are 17 digits long. Can anyone help me to figure out how to read that digits i.e. How to figure out the date, hour, minutes, etc. from it?

Also if possible, is there any way to convert it to Date Time in c#.

Here are the timestamps I am receiving:

> 38164862155703523,
>
> 38164862157000173,
>
> 38164862158301528

Comment: It could be ticks, try to use [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_).

Comment: @Sinatr I already tried that, but the date I am getting is incorrect.

Comment: What you have is a number. Unless you can explain what that number means, or someone happens to guess right, this question is futile

Comment: Do *you* know what datetime's those values are meant to correspond with? The problem is, there are a multitude of ways that an integer can be mapped to a datetime value.

Comment: @sinatr will you please explain this.

Convert(datetime, (MachineGroups.TimeAdded - 599266080000000000)/864000000000);

what is MachineGroups.TimeAdded, also the numbers.

Comment: It could be the amount of puppys born since 2/3/1103. who knows what it is. Edit your question so it has a remote chance of being answered. or explain when how and why you are getting this number, and what specification it belongs to

Comment: I am receiving this timestamp with the video streams. The library through which it is receiving is Microsoft.Skype.Bot.Media library.

Comment: @MurtazaMultan, it was some other guy code which didn't worked. Value `633896886277130000` corresponds to 1.11.2009 and your values are 20 times less. I am sure it's ticks, but not [standard ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?#remarks).

Comment: Ok maybe this is getting somewhere, https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/bot_media/Microsoft.Skype.Bots.Media.AudioMediaBuffer.html "*Timestamp of when the media content was received by the bot, or if the bot is sending media, the timestamp of when the media was sourced. It is in 100-ns units.*"

Comment: Next time you ask a question, make sure you have given the relevant information, this question was a train wreck in slow motion because you didn't supply any information